# Drawing stacked-bar chart using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to adapt this code:

http://bl.ocks.org/anupsavvy/9513382

To plot a stacked-bar chart using custom data. I don't need any transitions, just a simple plot.

I end up with this code:

```
data = jsonArr;

var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(colorrange);

var stack = d3.layout.stack();

stack(data);

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date(0, 0, 0, data[0][0].label, 0, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, data[0][data[0].length - 1].label, 0, 0, 0)])
  .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);


var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,
    d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d3.max(d, function(d) {
        return d.y0 + d.value;
      });
    })
  ])
  .range([height - margin.bottom - margin.top, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.time.hour, 1)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#info")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "rgroups")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colorrange[i];
  });

var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 6)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return -yScale(d.value) + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom);
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(new Date(0, 0, 0, d.label, 0, 0, 0));;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return -(-yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.value) + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) * 2);
  });

console.log(rects);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(40," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - 5)
  .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .text("Number of complaints");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "xtext")
  .attr("x", width / 2 - margin.left)
  .attr("y", height - 5)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Hour of day");
```

More specifically:

`yScale(d.y0)` is returning NaN.

If I comment this piece of code, I can see the axes:

After a while, I managed to see the and some data (among errors):

[image]

I guess I'm not understanding the properly way to plot the data itself.
Any help would be appreciated.

My `json` `label` attribute is related to the `y` coordinate, while `value` is related to the `x` coordinate.

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem begins when I call `stack`. The first array has `y0` values as `0`, but the second and third ones have `y0 = NaN`. I don't know how to fix this.

This is the relative jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rhzkz9gb/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the accessor functions for the data (because it is not keyed with 'x' and 'y').

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack().x(function(d,i){return i;}).y(function(d){return d.value;});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/rhzkz9gb/14/

Comment: OMG, thank you!  I spend my whole afternoon working on this plot. I figure it out about this **accessor** function but was trying to understand it now. Thank you!

Comment: do you how could I add legend? I'm trying to use `svg.selectAll("path")
     .attr("data-legend", function(d){ return d.name; })`, but now d.name is undefined.

Comment: To create a legend, you would need to create a 'g' element and attach to that a series of text and maybe a some graphic.  There are some generators people have created that can automate some of that (such as ZJONSSON's http://bl.ocks.org/ZJONSSON/3918369).

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, but now `d.name` is undefined.